# Laravel Remote/SSH catch SSH2 Exception

Tags: php, ssh, laravel-4, phpseclib

When im attempting to deploy things using laravel 4.1's SSH/Remote classes occasionally i get this exception

```
[2014-01-03 18:26:21] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Connection closed by server' in /home/{user}/{location}/deploy/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php:918
```

I was wondering if there is a way to detect if it has failed to connect in order to attempt the connection again and or multiple times?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel uses [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net) for its SSH library. On connection failure, phpseclib executes `user_error('Connection closed by server');` (see Net/SSH2.php, line ~911). Laravel has a global error handler that picks this up, and logs it (as you saw in your question).

Unfortunately, phpseclib triggers errors, instead of throwing exceptions. If they were exceptions, you could add a new condition to Laravel's error handling:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception){
    Log::error($exception);
    if($exception instanceof PHPSecLibException){
         // Let's handle this
    }
});
```

This definitely would be the "right way" to do it, but these aren't *true* exceptions (they're generic Laravel exceptions that are generated on your behalf when errors are triggered).

Luckily, Laravel translates errors into exceptions on your behalf. See [src/Illuminate/Exception/Handler.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/14716e50812860f27fb0d3d93d13f79fe70b8d63/src/Illuminate/Exception/Handler.php) (lines ~129-135). So we could just add a conditional based on the info you do have:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception){
    Log::error($exception);
    if(($exception->getMessage() == "Connection closed by server") &&
        ($exception->getFile() == "/home/{user}/{location}/deploy/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php")){
         // Let's handle this
    }
});
```

Take a look at the [Exception methods](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php) available.

Comment: So with that in mind is it possible to for instance if this error is fired attempt the connection again?

Comment: @ClarkT. Absolutely. I don't know enough about your codebase to tell you how exactly to do so, but if you're only using this the SSH library for only this one task, it should be easy enough to simply invoke the task again in the conditional (in the second code snippet I provided).

Comment: Is this the correct implementation of what you're suggesting? http://pastebin.com/XfWhu2iQ